# Symfony FosRest and NelmioCors A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, nelmiocorsbundle

I using FOSRestBundle with Nelmio Cors Bundle and have some endpoints, /api/name_end_points and I need for some server have authority to call this endpoints. 
Now I have error in console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com.com/api/endpoint?value=test&value1=test. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This my config:

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener: true
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        xml: true
        json : true
    templating_formats:
        html: true
    force_redirects:
        html: true
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: twig
routing_loader:
    default_format: json

nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: []
    allow_headers: []
    allow_methods: []
    expose_headers: []
    max_age: 0
    hosts: []
    origin_regex: false
paths:
    '^/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
```

How to correct config NelmioCorsBundle if I want access true for some server for my endpoints ? Like this

```
            allow_origin: ['*aog.jobs*', '*localhost*']
```

and deleted default ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly state that the origin (as specified in the `Origin` *request* header) is allowed to access the resource by copying the value of the `Origin` request header into the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` *response* header (instead of hard coding `*`).

Be very sure you want to make this globally accessible to the world before you do so (or perform a test on the value of the `Origin` header to make sure it is OK).

Comment: I not understand, I need access true for one or two server. Example  - mydomain.com. Whant I need write in config in nelmio_cors ?